# Better Control over test suites in SenTesting Kit/OCUnit

Tags: objective-c, ios, unit-testing

It seems that adding a class to my Xcode 4 Testing project that begins with test... automatically adds it to the testing run, but is there a way for me to have the test suites I want to run defined in a class so I can easily toggle them on and off? I would like to be able to manually register a suite then comment it out if it is not required. I don't want to have to add and remove classes from the Testing target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xcode4 Edit Scheme, select "Test", click the disclosure triangle and click "Test".  You will be able to select classes or individual tests.

[image]